# woocommerce - How Can I add author metadata for a product?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

Hi I am using woocommerce with Mystile Theme for a book store. How Can I add author taxonomy for a product?

I need to set an author for every book I am selling and possibly to search trough, author, categories, product names and tags.

Answer (score 1):

In the **Edit Product** screen, under the **Custom Fields** heading, create a new field, for example `product_author`. Then you need to edit your template file where you want to display the field, probably `content-product.php`, and call it this way:

```
<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'product_author', TRUE); ?>
```